# Using data- attribut with a hypertext link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have read this tutorial [tuto](http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1397-html5-attribut-data-dataset.html)

i'd like to use the attribut `data-` in a hypertext link:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="openbox2('Validation de concept technique', 1)" data-arr="@fa.Id_element" id="lien">Donner votre avis</a>
```

**in the javascript part**:

```
  function openbox2(formtitle, fadin) {
         var self = $(this);
         var arr = self.data('arr');
        alert(arr);
}
```

i get always the same alert message `undefined`.

What is the reason of this problem? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using inlined click handler, `this` inside the handler function does not refer tot he clicked element, you need to pass the reference as a parameter to the handler method

```
<a href="#" onClick="openbox2(this, 'Validation de concept technique', 1)" data-arr="@fa.Id_element" id="lien">Donner votre avis</a>
```

then

```
function openbox2(el, formtitle, fadin) {
    var self = $(el);
    var arr = self.data('arr');
    alert(arr);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xmq3N/)

Another solution is to pass a custom context to the `openbox2` method using [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
<a href="#" onClick="openbox2.call(this, 'Validation de concept technique', 1)" data-arr="@fa.Id_element" id="lien">Donner votre avis</a>
```

then

```
function openbox2(formtitle, fadin) {
    var self = $(this);
    var arr = self.data('arr');
    alert(arr);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cvA7k/)

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way you have attached your event, `this` is not the element which was clicked on. Using `on-` event attributes is very outdated now, and is not a good separation of concerns. As such it should be avoided. As you are already using jQuery for your logic it's best to also use it to attach your events:

```
<a href="#" data-arr="@fa.Id_element" id="lien" class="openbox">Donner votre avis</a>
```

```js
$('.openbox').click(openbox2);

function openbox2(formtitle, fadin) {
    var self = $(this);
    var arr = self.data('arr');
    alert(arr);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LK7Sx/)